# Consuming Azure REST API from Azure Functions with Azure AD Authentication using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, azure-functions

I try to call the Azure REST API from my Azure Functions with PowerShell.
It’s ok when I use MSI with the code below :

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)";
# Get an access token for the MSI
Write-Output "Endpoint: [$($env:MSI_ENDPOINT)]"
$apiVersion = "2017-09-01"
$resourceURI = "https://management.azure.com/"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:MSI_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=$apiVersion"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"Secret" = "$env:MSI_SECRET"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$ArmToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01"
$params = @{
ContentType = 'application/json'
Headers = @{
'authorization'="Bearer $ARMToken"
}
Method = 'Get'
URI = $uri
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$subscriptionId = $response.value.subscriptionId

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name
}

$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + $subscriptionId + "/resourcegroups?api-version=2018-02-01"

$params = @{
ContentType = 'application/json'
Headers = @{
'authorization'="Bearer $ARMToken"
}
Method = 'Get'
URI = $uri
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params | ConvertTo-Json
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $response
```

Now, my goal will be to authenticate users and use this authentication to call the REST API, in this way only the elements of my users will be obtained.

I activated the authentication for my functions :
[Activate Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC3FR.jpg)

[Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRGIq.jpg)

[Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nGYP.jpg)

I replace my code by this to display variables :

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)";

$Result = Get-Variable | ConvertTo-Json
```

Then I call my Functions, at the first call I’m prompting to allow it to “Connect and consult it’s profil”

[Allow authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbK7f.jpg)

In the result of execution I retrieve the variable "REQ_HEADERS_X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN" with the token.

[Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZwQx.jpg)

Then I try to reuse this token to authenticate my call to the REST API :

```
Write-Output "PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:$(get-date)"

$Result = Get-Variable -Name "REQ_HEADERS_X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN" | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json

$ARMToken =  $Result.Value

$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2016-06-01"
$params = @{
ContentType = 'application/json'
Headers = @{
'authorization'="Bearer $ARMToken"
}
Method = 'Get'
URI = $uri
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params

Out-File -encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject $response

$response
```

When I call my function I get this error message :

```
2018-06-04T09:53:55.476 [Info] Function started (Id=a9e8c744-8f29-4516-95ad-7218b60790ec)
2018-06-04T09:53:56.711 [Info] PowerShell Timer trigger function executed at:06/04/2018 09:53:56
2018-06-04T09:53:57.499 [Error] Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience","message":"The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource 'b46e2246-b8b5-4b33-897e-4702b6ddb868'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.azure.com/'."}}
at run.ps1: line 18
+ Invoke-RestMethod
+ _________________
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
2018-06-04T09:53:57.608 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerPowerShell1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: PowerShell script error. Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
2018-06-04T09:53:57.655 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=a9e8c744-8f29-4516-95ad-7218b60790ec, Duration=2167ms)
```

Someone have an Idea for how reuse the token to call the REST API using user authentication in an Azure functions ?